# Update a WordPress website FROM Twitter or Facebook

Tags: plugins, automatic-updates, automation, social-connect

I'm looking for a way to update a wordpress website when I post something to a specific twitter or facebook account.
Is it possible? Is there any plugin that do this?

I find only plugins that do the inverse, updating social networks from WordPress.
What I'd like to do is to update WordPress from my social network accounts.

Comment: I don't know of any.  However, I will point out this could negatively impact your site - if it is just full of a bunch of Tweets and status updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com) service.

You will have to [enable posting via XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) (enabled by default in WP 3.5+), Then you can create a recipe which uses Twitter or FaceBook as the trigger, and WordPress as the action. If you poke around, [someone has probably already created these recipes](https://ifttt.com/recipes?a=31&channel=wordpress&type=actions).